# Docker nginx ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose

hey so I setup vue with Nginx it worked just fine until yesterday I changed nothing but I get this when trying to access the website, it's not the Production system it is a Test System on Local Server [image]

my docker container status
[image]

also, I don't get logs with Portainer on the container Maby its important don't know. when I'm starting the docker container locally on my system it workes no problem

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine as evenman-frontend-build
ARG environment
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN npm install @vue/cli -g
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm audit fix
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build -- --mode $environment

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=evenman-frontend-build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx Config

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  sendfile on;
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /api;

      proxy_pass http://evenman-backend:8080/api;
    }

    location /oauth {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /oauth;

      proxy_pass http://evenman-backend:8080/oauth;
    }
  }
}
```

what I tried

- Restart Container
- Restart Docker Compose File
- Rebuild Container
- Rebuild Docker Compose File
- change Port From Docker Container
- Docker system prune

if you need more info on things just let me know I will add these then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed it it was the VPN Connection From my Company the port 8088 was not free in the Firewall so if you have the Same issue check your Firewall :D

Comment: change browser chrome is throwing this issue